# vector composition preserving convexity and perspective of a function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm reading Section 3.2.4 of the Boyd-Vandenberghe book on convex optimization, in the part about vector composition. It considers a function
$$ f(x) = h(g(x)) = h(g_1(x),\dotsc,g_k(x))$$
with $h~:~\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g_i~:~\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. W.l.o.g. it assumes $n=1$ because we can analyze the behavior of a function on each possible line.
It first shows how to derive rules for $h$ and the $g_i$'s so that $f$ is convex, under the condition that $h$ and the $g_i$'s are twice differentiable and their domain is respectively the whole $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}$. These rules involve the monotonicity of $h$.

Then, it says that general results hold with "no assumption on differentiability of $h$ or $g$, and general domains", but "the monotonicity condition on $h$ must hold for the extended-value extension of $\tilde{h}$". This restriction seems very strong, and I'm trying to understand whether I can relax it in some cases.

Specifically, I'm thinking of the following case: Let $z$ be a convex function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, with domain being the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider now the prespective of $z$, i.e., the function $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$ h(x,t) = t z\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)$$
This function has domain 
$$
\mathbf{dom}h = \{(x,t) ~:~ x/t \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0\},
$$
and is convex on this domain. Clearly this domain is not the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Assume we show that $h$ is non-decreasing **on its domain** wrt both $x$ and $t$. We would like to compose $h$ with functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ that are convex and getting that the resulting composition $f(x)=h(g_1(x),g_2(x))$ is convex, but according to the book we cannot just do it because the domain of $h$ is not the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Thus, we look at the extended-value extension $\tilde{h}$ of $h$, which is defined as $h(x,t)$ for $(x,t)\in\mathbf{dom} h$, and as $\infty$ everywhere else. Clearly $\tilde{h}$ cannot be non-decreasing: as we move from a point $(x,t_1)$ with $t_1\le 0$, to a point $(x,t_2)$ with $t_2>0$, the function goes from $\infty$ to something less than $\infty$.

Thus it seems that the composition rule "$f$ is convex if $h$ is convex and  non-decreasing in each argument, and $g_i$ are convex" cannot be applied to  the non-decreasing perspective of a convex function, because its extended-value extension will never be non-decreasing. Is that really true?

Are there rules or special cases in which I can apply a composition rule to such a perspective?

For example, what if $h$ and $g_i$ were twice differentiable on their domains?

In other words, is the monotonicity of the extended-value extension $\tilde{h}$ required only if the functions are not twice differentiable?

Comment: As for your final question, have you read Remark 3.3 in the book?

Comment: @LinAlg: I find that counterexample a bit disappointing: what if we restrict $g$ to $\mathbb{R}_{+}$? At this point, the domain of $f$ would be convex. I'm wondering whether, if we restrict the domain of the $h$ and of the $g_i$ so that the domain of the composition is convex, do we still care that $\tilde{h}$ is not non-decreasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $h(g(x))$ is convex if $h(g(x)) = \min_t\{h(t) : t \geq g(x) \}$ and $g$ and $h$ are convex. This requires $h$ to be nondecreasing on the range of $g$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference for the first part of your answer? I'll check and then I'll accept the answer, because I believe it solves my question.

Comment: Let $f(x,t)= t$ if $t \geq g(x)$, $\infty$ otherwise. Then $f$ is jointly convex in $(t,x)$ (easily checked via the definition of convexity with $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ and dealing with all finite/$\infty$ cases). The partial minimization of a jointly convex function is convex.

Comment: Another way to do this. Suppose $h$ is nondecreasing on the range of $g$; and let $y_\min=\inf_x g(x)$. Then define $\tilde{h}(y)=h(\max\{y,y_\min\}).$ This new function coincides with $h$ on the range of $g$, and is monotonic, so $\tilde{h}(g(\cdot))$ is convex; therefore, so is $h(g(\cdot))$.

Comment: Thank you both. I need some time to understand and internalize these suggestions, then I'll accept the answer and upvote the comments.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: I like your comment, but we must be careful because $y_{\min}$ may not be in the domain of $h$ (e.g., $y_\min=0$ but $\mathbf{dom}h=\mathbb{R}_{++}$), but we can probably just define $\tilde{h}$ as $h(y)$ if $y>y_\min$, and as the limit of $h(y)$ for $y\to y_\min$ otherwise. What do you think?

Comment: I think we just have to ensure that $\tilde{h}$ is right-continuous. I think that's going to be the case for any convex function but I am not certain.

Comment: @MichaelGrant $\tilde{h}$ is not necessarily nondecreasing. For $g(x)=0$ and $h(y)=-y$, you get $\tilde{h}(y) = -\max\{0,y\}$. For $y\geq y_\max = \sup_x g(x)$, you could let $\tilde{h}$ be equal to a linear approximation of $h$ at $y_\max$.

Comment: Ah, sure. So you need to be more careful on the right-hand side too. But can you think of a case where $g$ has a non-singleton range that would be problematic?

Comment: @MichaelGrant that's not so difficult, $g(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$, $h(y) = y$ on $[0,1]$, $h(y) = -y$ elsewhere. Then $\tilde{h}(y) = h(\max\{0,y\}) = y$ on $[0,1]$, $-y$ for $y>1$.

Comment: @LinAlg: going back to your answer, it's unclear to me how it generalizes when $h$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k>1$, so we have multiple $g_i$'s. What does the condition inside the $\min$ become?

Comment: @LinAlg is that $h$ convex? I’ve been assuming that

Comment: For that matter we can define $\tilde(h)=+\infty$ on the right

Comment: The $h$ that @LinAlg defined in the 2nd counterexample is not convex. Take $x=1.6$, $y=0.2$, and $\lambda=1/2$, and you get $h(1.6/2 + 0.2/2)=h(0.9)=0.9$ but $h(1.6)/2 + h(0.2)/2 = -0.8 + 0.1 = -0.7$.

Comment: @Matteo the answer would be the same, except that $t \in \mathbb{R}^k$.